# how to determine range potential of Pb in cyclic voltammetry?

Tags: electrolysis

standart potential of $\ce{Pb}$ is -0.13 V. how we determine an optimum potential of $\ce{Pb}$ sample? and how we choose the range potential?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! This seems to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) according to our policy, please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. For formatting help visit the [help] and for more information take the [tour].|| I admit, that I do not have any insight into cyclic voltammetry, so I can only give you a warm welcome :D

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more please?  It looks like you want to use a Pb working electrode for a CV experiment, yes?  And, what kind of solution will you be using for the experiment?  What is the goal of the experiment?  More info would be helpful.